# Why 3D visualization looks difficult in programming languages after half a century?

Tags: python, 3d, data-visualization

As my knowledge there is no fully satisfactory 3d visualization package. I mean fully because it is easily can be seen the following problems with available packages:

- lack of flexibility
- heavy loading and initializations (`ETS-Mayavi2,...`)
- very slow even with `OpenGL` implementations (`VPython,...`)
- lots of bugs for example under rotation and zooming
- unreliable for large data
- very old fashioned

Any help if you can address a satisfactory one for `Python` / `Fortran`?

Comment: Because it's a difficult area? There's a lot of inherent complexity to the problem and building a sane API around complex matters that is still powerful is **hard** (I suspect it's NP-hard ;-)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's probably because "fully" is hard to define.

Do you mean something like "The C++ of Visualization Libraries", where you can do boolean modeling, ray tracing, pixel shaders, transparent MAX file loading with acceleration structure compiling under the hood? With realtime LOTR-the-movie-battles animation as well as toon-shaders as well as scientific-visualization? Surface optimization builtin? Game engine and physics engine included, even if you only need three flat shaded triangles?

Such library would be extremely hard to write, alone the ray tracing component is worth hundreds of scientific papers, thousands of book pages (e.g. Pharr/Humphreys PBRT), years of study.  Same for surface simplification, terrain visualization, acceleration structures (see e.g. Vlastimil Havrans thesis), shader construction, performance optimizations (see e.g. Agner Fogs guides), streaming techniques for large datasets.

There are many engines, for different purposes.

The one true answer for your question therefore is: ***Because nobody has done it yet***.

Comment: I liked _"Because nobody has done it yet."_
And I understand why people don't wish to discuss this matter; the reason is nobody has a right answer or hope to get a result from discussion. As a developer always I have struggled with lack of visualization particularly scientific one. There are lots of libraries and standalone programs but most if not all of them just have reinvented principals again instead of providing a solution. Hope for coming decade there is a solution. I will be waiting ...